# Do swing states in the US count their votes faster due to external pressure?

Tags: united-states, election

On a related question [Why do California and New York need so much time to count their votes compared to other states?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/60071/why-do-california-and-new-york-need-so-much-time-to-count-their-votes-compared-t) Arcanist Lupus left the following comment:

> Critically, on a macro scale nobody cares what the results of the California and New York votes are. They're so blue that their races can be called early and there's very little pressure to get the exact count done quickly like there is in the swing states.

Is the above a true statement? Do swing states try to count their votes faster due to the whole country waiting to see the results, compared to states like New York which always vote Blue for the President and the Senate?

Comment: Assuming that [this list](https://ballotpedia.org/Election_results_certification_dates,_2016) is accurate, after sorting by date, I think the answer is "maybe to some extent, but not really all that much." But certification deadlines are not the same thing as vote counting, and I'm not sure how well they correlate.

Comment: I suspect this is much more compounded by various styles of voting rather than any sort of external pressure

Comment: Maybe they only end up going Dem because the counting takes so long... ;-)